# How to make directory outside of current directory?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, file-upload, permissions

I'm trying to create a secure way to handle file uploads by uploading the files to a directory outside of `public_html`.

I'm testing my script and my script works when I execute     `sudo php receive_files.php`, but when I run receive_files.php without     `sudo` I get     `failed to open stream: Permission denied.`

Right now all permissions all the way back to     `var/www/html/mysite/public_html` are set to 755. I tried changing all of them to 775 and the command still didn't work 
Without     `sudo`. And I'm pretty sure that would not be secure. How do I get around this problem?

My code:

```
$encoded_file = $_POST['file'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$decoded_file = base64_decode($encoded_file);

$new_directory = "../../../../../../user_uploads/$user_id/";

if(!file_exists($new_directory)){
    mkdir($new_directory, 0775, true);
    file_put_contents($new_directory . $decoded_file);
}
```

Comment: Permissions work like this: xyz - x = owner, y = group, z = all. If you change the permission to 775 and execute the file in command line the user you are running the command as either need to own the path, or be in the group that owns the path. Please add the output of `ls -l user_uploads` and `whoami && groups`. It should make it clear if there are any permission issues

Comment: All of var/www/ and its subdirectories are owned by root and belong to the root group. So are you saying I should change the owner and group to www-data?

Comment: The web server (ie www-data) needs access to the files (read/write depending on the file), and you need access to the files if you are going to run commands as another user than www-data (or a user that's in the www-data group).

Comment: So for both testing and running it from the web interface, I could add www-data and myself to a group, let's say scriptgroup. Then I could mimic what the php warnings/notices are when the user uploads from the web interface?

Comment: Just add yourself to the www-group, add the web dir/files to the www-group and set permissions as needed on the group permission, ie `chmod -R x7z user_uploads`

Answer (score 0):

Sudo is required when you are not the owner of something or you try to change permissions. So if you want php script to have access to upper directory.  Change the group or user owner of upper directory same as php executor, in most cases its www-data

You can check owner of php script by using

`ls -al`

Then change owner using

`chown -hR www-data:www-data directorypath`

For more detail check manual of chown command

This will most probably fix your issue

Additional info

> specifying absolute path instead of relative path solved the issue

Comment: I have tried changing the owner and group to www-data:www-data for /var/ and subdirectories down to receive.php (all of these directories: var/www/html/mysite/public_html/receive.php) but I am getting the same error

Comment: Does your script works under public_html, i mean when you create directly inside public_html

Comment: Yes it does. I had everything working previously with the files being written under public_html and all I did was add     ../../../../../../ to the     $new_directory variable

Comment: Try using complete path instead of relative path, like /var/html/somedir

Comment: also check comments regarding umask on this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: Specifying the absolute path worked! The user_uploads directory is now located in /var/user_uploads/ and is no longer web-accessible. Thank you friend